# Replace deck or paint house first?

Tags: paint

I need to have my house repainted and replace a large cedar deck. What order would you all suggest? Thanks.

Comment: Is the deck preventing access to any parts that need to be painted?

Comment: Do the painting, then it does not matter if you spill some.

Comment: Facetiously, yes.

Comment: This comes down to the nuances of your situation. Since you've given us none, we can't say. Please revise to provide detail and photos.

Comment: This is a very opinion-based question, so -1, but if it was me, I'd remove the deck, and install a new ledger (if applicable... ignore if this deck is freestanding), do all the flashing/ siding fixing, and then paint.

Answer (score 1):

Do the painting first that way if you spill something it doesn't matter (especially if you are doing it yourself) but keep a tin of paint just in case you need to touch up / paint some spots if the deck is in a slightly different place.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to play it safe, remove the old deck first. Then you can do the painting without any obstructions up against the walls. Afterwards, build your new deck.

Comment: OTOH, use the deck to get extra reach to the high spots that need to be painted. Hence, opinion based question. ;)

Comment: @FreeMan  I actually thought about that but figured if the deck was being replaced, it must be in bad shape and wouldn't want to be working on it.

Comment: There's a large span between "looks bad enough that it should be replaced because it's ugly and going to become a problem" and "on the brink of collapse and unsafe to stand on".  And that's ignoring pure size/aesthetic reasons someone might want to replace a perfectly good deck.